# SASS doesn't compile when one partial uses variable declared in another partial

Tags: sass

I have very small `hello world` SCSS project as follows:

**index.html**

```
<h1 class="heading-primary">Hello world!</h1>
```

**sass\main.scss**

```
@import "base/typography";    //Line A
@import "abstract/variable";
```

**sass/abstract/_variable.scss**

```
$color-white: #fff;
$color-black: #000;
$color-red: red;
```

**sass/base/_typography.scss**

```
.heading-primary {
  color: $color-red;
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile":"node-sass ./sass/main.scss css/style1.css -w"
  },
  "author": "sandeep",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Now if I run `npm run compile`, SASS does not compile and just shows this message

```
> starter@1.0.0 compile C:\Users\sandgup3\Desktop\NodeBook\advanced-css-course\Natours\test
> node-sass ./sass/main.scss css/style1.css -w
```

However, if I comment **Line A** in main.scss, SASS works perfectly file

```
=> changed: C:\Users\sandgup3\Desktop\NodeBook\advanced-css-course\Natours\test\sass\main.scss
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Users\sandgup3\Desktop\NodeBook\advanced-css-course\Natours\test\css\style1.css
```

Now if I uncomment **Line A** from main.scss I get this error:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "C:/Users/sandgup3/Desktop/NodeBook/advanced-css-course/Natours/test/sass/base/_typography.scss",
  "line": 3,
  "column": 10,
  "message": "Undefined variable: \"$color-red\".",
  "formatted": "Error: Undefined variable: \"$color-red\".\n        on line 3 of sass/base/_typography.scss\n>>   color: $color-red;\n   ---------^\n"
}
```

Also, if I directly import **_variables.scss** into **_typography.scss**, SASS compiles fine.

Can someone help debug this?
I have uploaded the file to GitHub for reference:[Link](https://github.com/sangupta007/scss-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. You're importing the partials in the wrong order. Import the variables first (always), then the rest of the partials that make use of the variables.

**sass\main.scss**

```
@import "abstract/variable";
@import "base/typography";
```

PS: The file should be called `variables` (plural).